# Problem with setting up a device for development

Tags: android

Pre-conditions:

- HTC USB driver installed
- HTC Desire HD connected to computer
- Command "adb devices" shows the device

Problem description:

How to activate device in Eclipse IDE? I can't see it in Android SDK and AVD Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this can be a few things.

One thing I always forget to do is on the device, make sure to set the USB Debugging Option on (Go to Home, press menu, select settings, select applications, select developement, ensure USB debugging is enabled).

Also  consult this page: [Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

Also then in eclipse switch to the DDMS perspective. While in there there should be a devices view. If it is empty, there is a little arrow that should be to the right of the camera capture button. Click that and select restart adb.

Answer (score 0):

It won't show up in the AVD Manager - this is for managing virtual Android devices in the emulator. If you have created an Android project in Eclipse, click "Run" and when the "Run As" dialog appears, choose "Android Application". If your phone is connected and showing up in `adb devices` your Eclipse project will automatically launch on your device.